# postfix still using ipv6 even if inet_protocols=ipv4

Tags: email, postfix, spf, ipv4

I have set this in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
inet_protocols=ipv4 
#I also tried with smtp_address_preference=ipv4
```

But still, the received message in Gmail shows an IPV6 address next to SPF. **Why?**

[image]

Comment: I posted the question anyway, but I think I might have found the reason: the email was sent from myself@example.com to check-auth@verifier.port25.com, and there was a "Bcc:myself123@gmail.com" to allow me to see the Original source of the email in gmail. *There* was the IPV6 adress (why? mystery!). Now when I do a simple `From:myself@example.com  To:myself123@gmail.com`, without any BCC, I can see an ipv4 address.

Answer (score 1):

The line you are looking at is not the whole story. The same message may result in travelling through both IPv4 and IPv6 as there might be more than one MTA-MTA connection. Therefore, you need to see the whole trace information, which Gmail shows on the same *Original Message* page.

The SPF check is done against the last MTA before Gmail. You can compare `Received-SPF` header with the `Received` header above it: that's the MTA checked for SPF validity. Then look further and see the very first (in time i.e. last in order) `Received` header: there you can see the original connection from your Postfix. If `inet_protocols=ipv4` was set and Postfix was restarted after the modification, there's no reason to believe that this is nothing but IPv4.